# How do MySQL determine target partition when execute select statement in key partition

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I create 8 key partitions, but each partitions row count is not flat.

The row counts of each partition has pattern: p0, p2, p4, p6 partition have 99.98% of rows, and p1, p3, p5, p7 partition have 0.02% of rows.

I want to fix it, so I wonder how MySQL determine the target partition when execute select statement.

Or, is there any better solution that can flatten this partition?

The mysql version is 5.7

Thanks.

Edit: I know the key partition works with `md5()` and mod. but I want to know how MySQL ACTUALLY calculate it.

Edit:

#### Schema

```sql
CREATE TABLE `WD` (
  `dId` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `wId` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`wId`,`dId`),
  KEY `idx_WD_w_d` (`wId`,`dId`),
  KEY `idx_WD_d_w` (`dId`,`wId`),
  KEY `idx_WD_w_u` (`wId`,`updatedAt`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50100 PARTITION BY KEY (workspaceId)
PARTITIONS 11 */
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `DA` (
  `id` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `wId` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(180) NOT NULL,
  `dId` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`workspaceId`),
  KEY `idx_DA_w_s_d` (`workspaceId`,`subject`,`documentId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50100 PARTITION BY KEY (wId)
PARTITIONS 11 */
```

Explain:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys                               key                     key_len ref                                         rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE      WD      p1          ALL     PRIMARY,idx_WD_w_d,idx_WD_d_w,idx_WD_w_u    NULL                    NULL    NULL                                        1       100.00      Using where; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      DA      p1          ref     idx_documentAcl_w_s_d                       idx_documentAcl_w_s_d   1266    const,const,DocumentService.WD.documentId   1       100.00      Using index
```

Comment: Rows are placed in a partition when you INSERT not when you SELECT? Or am I misunderstanding your question? It would be V.Useful if you showed us the schema for this table so we see how you partitioned it

Comment: @RiggsFolly when I use `explain select` with partition key in where clause, the partition is determined already. so I think there is some pattern that calculated with only partition key. That is my question! I added schema on question. Thanks!

Comment: Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` and copy/paste the output to your question

Comment: @RiggsFolly Editted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computation for picking the partition us quite lame, alas.  It is a simple modulo the number of partitions.

Key partitioning, in my opinion, is useless.  I know of no case where it helps performance, nor anything else.

Please provide the main queries that you will use with this table; I will explain how to make optimal indexes without using partitioning.  Or, in the rare case that partitioning is useful, I will explain what to do instead of what you are trying.

**A particular query**

Reformulating that query this way may help wit performance.

```
SELECT  WD.*
    FROM  WD
    JOIN  DA  ON WD.did = DA.did
    WHERE  WD.wid = '...'
      AND  DA.wid = '...'
      AND  DA.subject = '...'
    ORDER BY WD.updatedAt DESC  -- (per Comment)
    LIMIT 50;
```

And have these composite indexes, most of which you already have:

```
WD:  INDEX(wid, did)
WD:  INDEX(did, wid)
WD:  INDEX(wid, upddatedAt)
DA:  INDEX(wid, subject, did)
```

Be aware that UUIDs do not scale well.

Meanwhile, I see no performance benefit in Partitioning since the indexes should work quite well.

One more thing.  A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` gives you some random set of rows.  Note that adding an `ORDER BY` is likely to alter my advice on indexing.

You mentioned UUIDs -- does that mean you expect them to be Unique?  If so, do you really need `DA.id`?  (There may be a benefit to changing the PK of DA.)

Comment: Query is this:
`select * from DS.WD WD where WD.wId='some-wId-with-uuid' and WD.dId in (select DA.dId from DS.DA DA where DA.wId='some-wId-with-uuid' and DA.\`subject\`='some-subject-with-uuid-and-prefix') limit 50;`

Comment: DA schema is on the question!

Comment: Oh I have to use `ORDER BY updatedAt desc`.
And, on DA, wId is not unique in DA table. So I added id column, but if there is some better solution, it can be changed.

Comment: @Coalery - I added another index.  The Optimizer will pick among them; I can't predict which will be used.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for further discussion.

Comment: Editted! Please check the question.

Comment: @Coalery - Since there is only one row in p1, the Explain is rather useless.  Please replace it with a less trivial example.  What is the total number of rows in each table?

Comment: Each partition have about 6 million rows, and the `EXPLAIN` result on the question is for the query in your answer. Is simpler query needed?

Comment: @Coalery - "Each partition have about 6 million rows" disagrees with your statement "p0, p2, p4, p6 partition have 99.98% of rows, and p1, p3, p5, p7 partition have 0.02% of rows."  I would like you to run the Explain when some fat partition is involved.

Comment: Oh, I solved it! I missed original question.. Idk why but I found the rule of it. The rows that `workspaceId` includes only even unicode (like `24428`, `42886` ...) are going to odd partition (like p1, p3, ...) and all the rest are going to even partition. The uuid column includes hyphen which has 45 by unicode(or ascii code) so all of them going to even partition. Almost of rows have uuid `workspaceId` so p0, p2, p4, p6.. partition has 99.98% of rows.

Comment: So I partitioned it with 11 partition, then the rows are partitioned flat. Thanks for continuous helping!!!

Comment: @Coalery - Glad that was fixed.  But there is still the question of whether Partitioning provides _any benefit_.

Comment: I test processing time by four cases: `no index, no partitioning`, `index, no partitioning`, `no index, partitioning`, `index, partitioning` with 10 query. And the result is, partitioning is not giving any benefit in my dataset.